# Limit font size using System.Drawing.Font?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, system.drawing

I am using the in built Font dialog to choose the font size and the style. The font size range shows from 8 to 72. I need to restrict users not to choose the size beyond 20. Is it possible to disable the font size from 22 or not display them at all from 22? I don't see any property on the Font class to do this? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't see any property on the Font class to do this?

That's because it is a property on the FontDialog class, not the Font class.  For example:

```
    using (var dlg = new FontDialog()) {
        dlg.MaxSize = 20;                               // <=== Here
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            // etc...
        }
    }
```

And you'll see that you can't possibly pick a size larger than 20.